# Channel.Ping.Failed error Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions What's the root cause?

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm

Hi
I've downloaded the Cairngorm3 Simple Sample Application from [here](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/wiki/SimpleSampleApplicationExplained/).
There's a few steps.
a) Download the server-side zip. It contains a PDF instructing how to start a HSQLDB database and get a Tomcat instance up an running (I used catalina.sh start).
b) Check out the source with Subversion, and load it up into Flashbuilder 4. (You need Flex 3.4 SDK)
When I run the app (an Outlook like app written in Flex), I have issues at the point I try and save a contact. I'm assuming it's on a remoteobject call.
But it I get this:

Send failed
faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Ping.Failed error Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled to manage the client connection correctly. url: 'http://localhost:8400/messagebroker/amf;jsessionid=5765DDDB6E2D54BD03D3E636B0E8C03E'''

I'm wondering if this is something you need to tweak in services-config.xml?
Located in flex-frameworks/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/flex folder (flex-frameworks comes from the server-side zip download:

Anyone got any ideas?
This is Christophe Coenraets baby.

I also subsequently found a [blog post by Alexander Glosband](http://www.alexglosband.com/?p=3), but couldn't ascertain from it, what you need to do as a work around. i.e. Is this something that is configurable?

The way to reproduce the error consistently is to try and activate the web camera from the app. Then instead of clicking accept, reload the screen. Then when you try and take a photo after subsequently granting access to camera, you get the duplicate session error.
I think there is an issue with the code pertaining to the Camera, that's not cleaning up after itself correctly, the session is probably not being tidied up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, problem comes from services-config.xml. Change your url from

```
http://localhost:8400/messagebroker/amf
```

to

```
/messagebroker/amf
```

I found solution from here [send failed error](http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/07/26/flex-remoting-urls-and-understanding-the-send-failed-error/)

"Compiler EMBEDS channels, endpoints and destinations into SWF" video tells.